# Create "invisible" graphics

Tags: java, image, invisible, off-screen, raw-data

I need Your help in generating offscreen images from graphics class and converting them to binary data without setting them visible on screen.
I want to generate large amounts of labels and send them to a printer as binary data. If i create the image, show it on screen and then send it, everything is ok, but i generate 100 labels in one minute and it is annoying when they flicker on the screen of my java aplication.
I want it to be generated by a seperate thread, without visible efects.
If i don't show them, the labels are send black. I tried to generate them, and then show them off screen, that did not match my expectations.
Is there a way to generate "invisible" images from Graphics2d??
or 
Is there another way You could suggest me?

Thank You in advance
Qba

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and use [`getGraphics()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getGraphics%28%29) to get hold of a `Graphics2D` object that paints onto this image.

If you're after painting GUI components (if your "label" refers to JLabel for instance) you could have a look at these questions:

- [How to get a BufferedImage from a Component in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857901/how-to-get-a-bufferedimage-from-a-component-in-java)
- [Java/Swing offscreen rendering (Cobra HTMLPanel -> BufferedImage) Problem: Component doesn't finish redrawing first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783377/java-swing-offscreen-rendering-cobra-htmlpanel-bufferedimage-problem-compo)

Comment: Thank You for Your response. I already use a BufferedImage and getGraphics(). This is my method:

Comment: Thank You for Your response. I already use a BufferedImage and getGraphics(). I have a class that extend a JPanel, I draw some graphics on it in the paint method, then I create a new BufferedImage and then a use image.getGraphics() to paint onto that image. But to launch the paint method i need to add it to a paintable component like a JDialog and make it visible on the screen, and I would prefer not to do that. I want to create an image from my elements like strings, barcodes, and somehow draw them to a bufferedImage without using the paint method or without makeing the component visible. Qba

Comment: *Why* do you need to make it visible on the screen? To launch the paint method? What do you need the paint method for?